# Is there an event listener for scrolling?

Tags: android, events, scrollview, listener, scale

I want to Scale an ImageView when the user scrolls.I tried searching for event listeners, but didn't really understood what to do.

Its more like shrinking an image when the user scrolls down and bringing back to the initial size when the top is reached.
Can someone help me with this one?

Thanks!

Comment: can u show your code ?

Comment: try scalegesturedetector